# how to find the kernel for salt and paper/speckle noise in order to apply Wiener filter | Python

Tags: python, image-processing, wiener-filter

***hi guys greetings***

I am doing a research, where I should apply a Wiener filter on a number of images that are affected by several types of noises like speckle and salt&paper noise, then I will calculate the PSNR values of each filtered image to find the effectiveness of filtering these types of noises using the wiener filter, from what I understand about wiener filter that I need to deconvolve the blurring kernel that's being applied on an image, and luckily I found this code on the web that shows how to apply a wiener filter, and here how its look :

**first: setting up the blurring kernel**

```
def gaussian_kernel(kernel_size = 3):
    h = gaussian(kernel_size, kernel_size / 3).reshape(kernel_size, 1)
    h = np.dot(h, h.transpose())
    h /= np.sum(h)
    return h
```

**second: define the wiener filter**

```
def wiener_filter(img, kernel, K):
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    dummy = np.copy(img)
    dummy = fft2(dummy)
    kernel = fft2(kernel, s = img.shape)
    kernel = np.conj(kernel) / (np.abs(kernel) ** 2 + K)
    dummy = dummy * kernel
    dummy = np.abs(ifft2(dummy))
    return dummy
```

**finally: apply the filter**

```
kernel = gaussian_kernel(3)
filtered_img = wiener_filter(noisy_img, kernel, K = 10)
```

***The issue*** that I faced, is that I don't know how to apply the same filter on images being affected by noises like Speckle or Salt&Pepper, so I don't know what to do, should I keep the blurring kernel as it is here and apply the wiener filter function on my noised images, or should I approximate a kernel for the Speckle/Salt&Pepper noise, and if so, how to do it?

thanks in regard, and I want to mention :

- I know you may find the same question being published on StackOverflow, but it's for Matlab, not python.
- I really tried hard and did a lot of research before publishing my question here, but I still can't figure out just this problem in wiener filters.

*and I really appreciate every reader's time, and sorry if I took long.*

Comment: There is a difference between the Wiener filter for deconvolution and for noise reduction. The Gaussian kernel you use is related to deconvolution, it has nothing to do with the distribution of your noise.

Comment: oh, thanks,. now I understand, so the code will not work for noise reduction at all, I mean for example imagine that I found a kernel for the speckle or salt&pepper noise and then i plugged it into the main wiener_filter function, like above, it still won't work for noise reduction, is that what you mean ???\

Comment: @CrisLuengo 
i mean is this what you meant about a wiener filter that can be used for noise reduction 
"scipy. signal.wiener"

Comment: A Weiner filter's premise is to apply deconvolution to an input image.  The best way to reduce salt-and-pepper noise is by a median filter, which cannot be represented by deconvolution.  Deconvolution as an operator is **linear** where a median filter is **non-linear**.

Comment: @rayryeng 
thanks sir, I really appreciate your reply.
I know that the best way to reduce Salt&Pepper noise is by using a median filter, 
but in my research, I'm required to test the wiener filter to reduce Salt&Pepper noise, in order to measure its efficiency in reducing that noise.

so I still don't know how to apply a wiener filter on Salt&Pepper noise :(

Comment: I honestly do not know what the best method is.  You can try blind Weiner deconvolution method that is in another question that you asked the other day - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992908/can-scipy-signal-wiener-filter-reduce-noise/71994118#71994118